# Disable DTR when opening the serial port from pyserial running on a Mac

Tags: python, arduino, pyserial

I have the following code:

```
import sys,serial
ser = serial.Serial()
ser.baudrate=57600
ser.port = sys.argv[1]
ser.dsrdtr = True
ser.open();
ser.setDTR(level=False)               

print ser.readline()
```

The thing is that my Arduino UNO receives a DTR and restarts, how can I disable this (in software)? My python code is running from a Mac mini with a usb connection to my UNO.

(I'm fully aware of [this](http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/DisablingAutoResetOnSerialConnection) but hardware is not an option for me)

Answer (score 0):

I'm having similar issues, but haven't been able to find a solution for a while. Looks like this is possible on Windows [with some hackery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15460865/disable-dtr-in-pyserial-from-code?rq=1), but the issue lies deeper on posix.

Ideally you should be able to setDTR before you open the connection. Like this:

```
import sys,serial
ser = serial.Serial()
ser.baudrate=57600
ser.port = sys.argv[1]
ser.dsrdtr = True
ser.setDTR(level=False)
ser.open();

print ser.readline()
```

But that throws a portNotOpenError in serialposix.py:

```
def setDTR(self,on=1):
    """set terminal status line"""
    if not self.fd: raise portNotOpenError
    if on:
        fcntl.ioctl(self.fd, TIOCMBIS, TIOCM_DTR_str)
    else:
        fcntl.ioctl(self.fd, TIOCMBIC, TIOCM_DTR_str)
```

I took a dive into [serialposix.py](ftp://ftp.ti.com/pub/data_acquisition/ADS1100EVM/Source/ads1100evm-src-1_0/serial/serialposix.py), and you'll see where the root issue lies. That self.fd defined above is actually:

```
self.fd = os.open(self.portstr, os.O_RDWR|os.O_NOCTTY|os.O_NONBLOCK)
```

If you write a little script that opens your device using `os.open(device, flags)`, you'll see it resets, even if you open it as read only with the flag `os.O_RDONLY`.

Digging deeper into the [meaning of the `os.open` flags](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#open-constants)- we find that the open command actually wraps the unix command open(2). The man pages are [here](http://linux.die.net/man/2/open).

Let me know if you ever find a more satisfactory solution.