# pyserial and arduino can't send data to arduino

Tags: python-3.x, arduino, pyserial

I try to send an integer from python script to arduino, analize it on board and send an integer to python script. I can reciev data from arduino, but I can't send data to arduino because it reboots. Also, it works with Arduino IDE

The idea is that i send through python magicnumber = 387, than arduno compare it with its owm MN = 387 and than send MN to python, but also, when i start sending data from python it rebooting and nothing work. if it can be please answer mostly with code, 'cause i'm not very goodin English. Thanks

```
int magicNumber;//глобальные переменные
bool connection = false;
void setup()
{
    pinMode(infoLed, OUTPUT);
    Serial.begin(baudrate);
    while (!Serial) {
        fastBlink();
    }
    slowBlink();

    EEPROM.get(magicNumberAddr, magicNumber);
    normalBlink();
    waitForMN();
}

void loop()
{
    if (!connection) {
        waitForMN();
    }

    slowBlink();

}

void waitForMN() {//двустороннее квинтирование
    String data = "";
    byte sizeofbuf = 0;
    while (Serial.available() <= 0) {
        fastBlink();
    }
    while (!connection) {
        if (Serial.available()) {
            sizeofbuf += 1;
            char s = Serial.read();
            data = String(data + s);
            Serial.println(data.toInt());

            if (sizeofbuf == 3) {
                if (data.toInt() == magicNumber) {
                    Serial.println(magicNumber);
                    char k = Serial.read();
                    connection = true;
                    break;
                } else {
                    Serial.read();
                    waitForMN();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

python:

```
import serial
import time
ser = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyUSB1",9600,timeout=10)

ser.flush()
ser.write(str("387").encode())
time.sleep(1)
ser.write(str("387").encode())

print(ser.readline())
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable DTR in pyserial from code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15460865/disable-dtr-in-pyserial-from-code)

Answer (score 0):

It's actually hard to answer your question because you posted an incomplete code and also I have no any info about whatever you are getting an error from python script.

Arduino reboots after opening a serial port and it's a bootloader standard behavior. You can read more about it on the [arduino web page](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Hacking/Bootloader). But actually that means, that your sketch will start to work after about ~3 seconds after connecting to serial port. Just put time.sleep(3) in your python code right after the serial connection initialization and your script must work as intended.

P.S. Consider using Serial.[parseInt](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/ParseInt)() instead of that bulky construction in waitForMN() function of Arduino sketch.